# How does $_POST like to receive multiple parameters if they came in one string?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post

I'm trying to get an Ajax call working in JQuery, PHP and MySQL.

I have two variables I need to send: `$speaker_id` and `$article_id`.

I'm constructing my jQuery like so:

```
$('.ajax-call').click(function() {
    var speakerID = <?=$speaker_id?>;
    var articleID = $(this).attr('id');
    var ajaxData  = 'speaker_id=' + speakerID + ', article_id=' + articleID;
    $.ajax({
        type:     'POST',
        url:      'update-read-article.php',
        data:     ajaxData,
        dataType: 'text'
    });
});
```

However, checking Chrome's Developer Tools "Network" tab once the call has been made, I see that `update-read-article.php`'s received Form Data looks like so:

```
speaker_id: 16551, article_id
```

and not the expected:

```
speaker_id: 16551
article_id: 29
```

How can I construct my `ajaxData` so that my script can find both `$_POST['speaker_id']` and `$_POST['article_id`?

Comment: trim your code up a bit.  You have some extra spaces in the `ajaxData` var, and similarily, you use a comma, whereas for AJAX, you use `&`.  Example:  hello.com?a=45&b=22.  It works the same way with get and post parameters.

Comment: AJAX is just a regular HTTP request that happens to be done "in the background". You have to conform to what the HTTP spec's requirements for data submission - your code isn't, which is why you're getting this wonky string on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must separate each parameter with "&". Comma's or other characters won't work, so remove them.

Your query string should look like:

```
var ajaxData  = 'speaker_id=' + speakerID + '&article_id=' + articleID;
```

Comment: This was the answer I read and used first, so I'm accepting this one. All others get an up-vote. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Querystring values must be separated by an ampersand (`&`) not a comma (no space after the `&`):

```
var ajaxData  = 'speaker_id=' + speakerID + '&article_id=' + articleID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `ajaxData` may be defined the same way as query string but with request type `POST` this will be translated into *post* parameters.

Like so:

```
$('.ajax-call').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:     'POST',
        url:      'update-read-article.php',
        data:     'speaker_id=<?=$speaker_id?>&article_id=' + $(this).attr('id'),
        dataType: 'text'
    });
});
```

Mind the *ampersand* (`&`) delimiting the parameters - same way as in query string (GET).

Or you may define that data as object:

```
$('.ajax-call').click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type:     'POST',
        url:      'update-read-article.php',
        data:     {
            'speaker_id': <?=$speaker_id?>,
            'article_id': $(this).attr('id')
        },
        dataType: 'text'
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use jQuery `$.param({speaker_id: yourval, article_id: yourval})`. You won't get confused with building the string manually.

Have you tried outputting `ajaxData` to console?